# Can't instantiate class even included

Tags: php, include, instantiation

I'm very new to PHP, and I can't solve an issue even I read a lot of tutorials and SO posts.
I've a custom class (user), and I'd like to instantiate it in php code, but even I include it, I get this error.

> Fatal error: Class 'User' not found in D:\wamp64\www\MyFirstPhp\formPhp.php on line 17

Please help me find out what I do wrong.

Here is my user class:

```
  <?php
/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: molnard
 * Date: 2017. 06. 06.
 * Time: 15:36
 */

namespace infopro;


class User
{
    private $username;
    private $userage;
    private $sex;

    public function __construct($username, $userage, $sex)
    {
        if (!is_null($username)) $this->username = $username;
        if (!is_null($userage)) $this->userage = $this->userage;
        if (!is_null($sex)) $this->sex = $sex;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $username
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserage()
    {
        return $this->userage;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $userage
     */
    public function setUserage($userage)
    {
        $this->userage = $userage;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSex()
    {
        return $this->sex;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $sex
     */
    public function setSex($sex)
    {
        $this->sex = $sex;
    }
}
?>
```

And here is my form.php class where I'd like to instantiate user class.

```
    <!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form php</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include("User.php");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$sex = $_POST["sex"];
echo "New user<br>name: " . $name . "<br>" .
    "age: " . $age . "<br>" . "sex: " . $sex."<br>";

$newuser = new User($name, $age, $sex);
$newAge = $newuser->getAge();
echo $newAge;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you may have forgotten to use the namespace where User is in.

Comment: `namespace infopro;`.... your class is [namespaced](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php): `$newuser = new \infopro\User($name, $age, $sex);`

Comment: It works for me, even without name space. What is your PHP runner? what is it version? what is your project struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception already told you, whats wrong with your code. There's no such `User` class. If you use namespaces, and your currently in another namespace (or no namespace), you have to use fully qualified names. Means: namespace + classname.

In your case, you have to prefix your class name with the namespace `infopro`, which leads to `\infopro\User`

```
$user = new \infopro\User(...);
```

If you don't want to use always the fqn and you are in a diffrent namespace, you could also import the classname into the local scope of the file with `use`.

```
use \infopro\User;

// somewhere later ...
$user = new User(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$newuser = new \infopro\User($name, $age, $sex);
```

Or

```
<?php 
use \infopro\User;
?>
    <!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form php</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include("User.php");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$sex = $_POST["sex"];
echo "New user<br>name: " . $name . "<br>" .
    "age: " . $age . "<br>" . "sex: " . $sex."<br>";

$newuser = new User($name, $age, $sex);
$newAge = $newuser->getAge();
echo $newAge;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using namespace in your class you'll have to use that namespace to properly include User class.

try adding `use \infopro\User;`:
    `

```
<?php
    include "User.php";

    use \infopro\User;
    $name = 'talib';
    $age = '29';
    $sex = 'male';
    echo "New user<br>name: " . $name . "<br>" .
        "age: " . $age . "<br>" . "sex: " . $sex."<br>";

    $newuser = new User($name, $age, $sex);
    $newAge = $newuser->getUserage();
    echo $newAge;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, all answer was good.
I use intelij, and I've just realised namespace just optional, I can use global namespace if I leave it blank.